# Getting an NTLM Challenge from an AJAX POST on just one page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication

Quite the mystery here. I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application using Windows Authentication that has been maintained for over 18 months without issue.  Recently, it was deployed to a fresh site and I've encountered the following, very strange behavior.

I am using a jQuery 1.8.2 `$.ajax` call to POST data to the server endpoints to update data.  This works just fine except on one page, where the AJAX POST triggers a new NTLM Negotiation.  The same problem is exhibited in Chrome, IE, and Firefox.  While the issue is the same in all the browsers, it manifests itself in slightly different ways:

- Firefox : Received a 401 Challenge response from the server and brings up a username/password dialog asking for credential in an infinite loop.  Canceling the credential checks causes the request to fail with an Unauthorized response.
- IE : No response from the server and the request status shows as "(Aborted)" in the Network monitor
- Chrome : No response from the server and the request status shows a "(failure)" in the Network monitor.

The core issue seems to be that the `Connection: keep-alive` header is not being sent with the problematic AJAX request, but is in the other cases.  However, the underlying JavaScript code is nearly identical, and the AJAX calls function properly in a development environment that is also set up to use Windows authentication.

Also, attempting the set the `Connection` request header in the `beforeSend` callback has no effect.

Any insights into the root of the problem, or ways to isolate whatever difference exists between the two AJAX POSTs are most appreciated.

**Working Code and Request Headers**

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: "POST",
   data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
   cache: false,
   success: function (response) {
   }
});


Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:621
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:www.xxx.yyy.zzz
Origin:http://www.xxx.yyy.zzz
Referer:http://www.xxx.yyy.zzz/app/resource/path
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

**Failing Code and Request Headers**

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    }
 });

 WARN: Provisional headers are shown
 Accept:*/*
 Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
 Origin:http://www.xxx.yyy.zzz
 Referer:http://www.xxx.yyy.zzz/app/resource/item/1
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
 X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

I have also looked at the network process in the Chrome `chrome://net-internals/#events` viewer.  Here is the event log from the failed request at the point it deviates from the successful one. Where the failed request gets an "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized" the successful request gets an "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" response, presumably due to the presence of the `Connection: keep-alive` header.

```
2303: URL_REQUEST
Start Time: 2015-04-28 13:53:41.788

t=14736 [st= 0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=71]
t=14736 [st= 0]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=14736 [st= 0]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=70]
                   --> load_flags = 2688000 (BYPASS_DATA_REDUCTION_PROXY | MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | REPORT_RAW_HEADERS | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
               --> method = "POST"
               --> priority = "LOW"
               --> upload_id = "0"
               --> url = "http://..."
t=14736 [st= 0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=14736 [st= 0]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=14736 [st= 0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=14736 [st= 0]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=14736 [st= 0]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                       --> source_dependency = 2305 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=14736 [st= 0]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=14736 [st= 0]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=14736 [st= 0]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                       --> POST ... HTTP/1.1
                       Host: www.xxx.yyy.zzz
                       Connection: keep-alive
                       Content-Length: 105
                       Accept: */*
                       Origin: http://www.xxx.yyy.zzz
                       User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
                       X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
                       Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
                       Referer: http://www.xxx.yyy.zzz/app/resource/item/1
                       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
                       Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
t=14736 [st= 0]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_BODY
                       --> did_merge = true
                       --> is_chunked = false
                       --> length = 105
t=14736 [st= 0]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=14736 [st= 0]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=0]
t=14736 [st= 0]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=0]
t=14736 [st= 0]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS
                   --> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
                       Content-Type: text/html
                       Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
                       WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
                       WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
                       X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
                       X-UA-Compatible: IE=9
                       Date: Tue, 28 Apr 2015 18:53:41 GMT
                       Content-Length: 1293
```

**Edit**

Playing around with different request from the console gives the following table of results (under Chrome).  The current base URL is `http://IPAddress
/app/topic/item` and all test simply execute an `$.ajax({ url: url, type: 'POST' })`

```
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|   URL                                | Response                   |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| http://IP/app/topic/item/1/subitem/1 | net::ERR_INVALID_HANDLE    |
| //IP/app/topic/item/1/subitem/1      | net::ERR_INVALID_HANDLE    |
| /app/topic/item/1/subitem/1          | net::ERR_INVALID_HANDLE    |
| 1/subitem/1                          | net::ERR_INVALID_HANDLE    |
| 1/foo                                | 404 (Not Found) [expected] |
| 1                                    | 302 (Redirect)  [expected] |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Because the error **only** affects a subset of the `POST` action methods in one controller, I had initially thought this was a server-side issue, but after uncovering the issue of the missing `Connection` header, it actually appear to be a client-side issue.  Exactly how the problem is triggered remains a mystery to me.

I did also verify that the Response headers for the working page and the problematic page are the same.  Most relevant, the `Persistent-Auth: true` header is always returned in both cases.

Comment: Have you tried implementing the `error` handler from the `ajax` call? you might get some extra information here?

Comment: @christiandev Yes. Chrome returns a net::ERR_INVALID_HANDLE error code and IE has an error code of 12019, which is documented to be ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE.  Firefox also reports an "Invalid Handle".

Comment: One other thing, I added [GET] routes that match all of my [POST] routes just in case this was a weird manifestation of the GET-before-POST issue that is known about IE and IWA. This had no effect.

Comment: I don't see any content length in the failing post. Are you posting any data?

Comment: @Mike Yes, I just verified that there is form encoded data in the body of the POST.  The headers were what Chrome Dev tools displayed and were marked as provisional headers. I captured the request from Fiddler and it does have a Content-Length of 106, which matches the body content.

Comment: Can you post the code for the click handlers and the exact urls used in you examples?

Comment: @Mike Here are the HTML fragments and event handlers for both cases.  The working case is a form submit event, the failing case is a click event on a span. http://pastebin.com/DGCvimD8

Comment: Is the url you're using the same protocol, host and port as the page itself? It isn't sending an Authorization header.

Comment: What version of IIS was the site on previously and what version is it on now? Also, have you configured and enabled failed request tracing in IIS?

Comment: @JamieSee The version of IIS is 7.5 and it did not change between deployments.  The updated application was simply set up as a new application on the existing server.  Yes, failed request tracing is enabled, but the request does not fail, but rather the client stops sending the authentication token (for just POSTs mapped to one controller) and we get stuck in an endless loop of 401 responses.

Comment: I am running into this issue sporadically uploading small xlsx files. Same version of jQuery and I am on MVC 3 in Chrome. Refreshing the page causes the issue to go away. No idea what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Some wild guesses:

- This happens when you request a Role that is not in the Claims of the currently logged-in user. Verify that, if you're using `[Authorize(Roles = "xyz")]`, the current user actually has that role.
- It is not clear if your application uses a cookie for authentication. If yes, you should see it with the request. Are you setting `withCredentials: true` for each request?

Comment: You might be on to something, here. We have a security setup that leverages our own ActionFilter attributes, so it could be a back-end data issue related to user->role mappings.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No luck. The user has the correct roles and, in fact, the `AuthorizeAttribute` is set as a Global Filter, so all of the requests should fail if this were the problem.  Also, using Glimpse, the AJAX request never even hits the .Net pipeline; it's immediately aborted. The only difference I noted between the development and production environment is that the problem occurs on IIS 7.5 and not on my local IIS 8.5.  I'll try running locally under IIS Express 7.5 to see if that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Lucas You should redact the MIME from the Negotiate header in your dumps. It can be decoded to get info you probably don't want exposed.

Comment: Perhaps check out this answer, particularly consider browser configuration and ensure setting of withCredentials attribute - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47916916/5196274

Answer (score 0):

What's happening in the action methods that are causing the NTLM challenge ? Are you sure these specific action methods aren't accessing another server, or the internet through a proxy which requires authentication ? In your development environment, your user or the user running the app pool on IIS may have the necessary permissions, but the user on the server may not.

Instead of throwing a clear security-related Exception, ASP.NET will translate this into an NTLM challenge being returned to the client, and a 401 in case of invalid credentials, instead of a 500 containing the stacktrace leading you to the point where the server account didn't have sufficient privileges...