# Trigger TFS Release Management with Artifact Version Number

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, release-management, devops, ms-release-management

I am excited to see TFS Update 2 available for on premise and including the Release Management Feature part of the web experience.  We have been waiting for this.

I need some help on how best to trigger the release.

A release can be triggered in 3 ways:

- Continuous Deployment Trigger based on linking to TFS Build Definition
- Manually
- REST API

This is great but I don't think it fits what I would expect.  I need help in a technical solve or in how I think about the problem.

**My Thinking:**

I believe the Build should create an artifact and put the artifact in a Drop location to be released now or a year from now. (need to rebuild or add a server later)

I feel the continuous deployment trigger breaks down as it depends on the artifact being in the TFS Build and the TFS Build will be deleted depending on your settings.

**Possible Solution:**

I believe the solution I need is to create a draft release using the REST Api and then pass in the path to the artifact in the drop location.  In my case I would simply provide a version number and build the path inside the release.

**Problem:**

At this point the REST api is not documented.

I appreciate your thoughts on my thinking.  It could be that I'm thinking about the problem in the wrong way.

Also, If anyone knows how to create a release using the REST api that would likely get me to where I need to be.

I see the REST api is to be documented at the following spot but is is not yet.  I really want to get going, I have over 100 apps to deploy.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/release/managing-releases/create-release#CreateareleasebyusingtheRESTAPI

Answer (score 2):

We also use TFS 2015 update 2 on-prem and use PowerShell to interface with TFS REST API.

As stated in comments on this thread the REST API documentation is live and to create a release refer to the following link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#create-a-release

To answer your question: - to create a release using a PowerShell script try the following:

```
$filePath = "C:\PATH_TO_JSON"
$username =  'DOMAIN\USRNAME'
$password  =  'PASSWORD'
$body = Get-Content $filePath
$resource = "http://TFS_URL/_apis/release/releases`?api-version=2.2-preview.1"
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$resource" -Credential $cred -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
```

The **$filePath** variable should point to a file containing the following JSON markup.  Be sure to alter the variables within the example JSON to fit your on-prem Release Definition:

```
{
  "definitionId": 12,
  "description": "M 98 release",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "Fabrikam.CI",
      "instanceReference": {
        "id": "90"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

> You could also use JavaScript to interface with TFS REST API.  See the post by @Elmar here:  [TFS 2015 REST API Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072327/tfs-2015-rest-api-autentication/36076642#36076642)

Answer (score 1):

The Release Management API docs for VSTS are live [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/rm/releases). Most of the APIs should work for TFS 2015.2 also.

For creating a new release, refer to my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635473/vs402881-no-artifact-version-is-specified-corresponding-to-artifact-source-myb/36638300#36638300) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can retain a build indefinitely so it will always be available when you need it. [image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That is not exactly the approach that I would want.  That would require a manual process to mark it as retain indefinitely.

Would you know how to kick off release via REST?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

ReleaseManagement REST API got public at

https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/rm/releases#Createarelease. Please have a look. While creating the release pass three things in the artifact :- alias, instanceReference (name and Id).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, 
it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here 
and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes