# Connecting tfs api using javascript

Tags: javascript, tfs, tfs-sdk, azure-devops-rest-api

I've done a new database with a user interface (with Javascript code) and Iam trying to connect the UI with TFS API to get some informations and save it in my Databas
but i have challenge in establishing this connectioin with Javascript 
can anyone help me please??

Comment: Could you describe what you did to solve the problem on your own?

Comment: Which TFS version, most REST API's are not supported in versions older than TFS 2015? Are you using the vso-node-api? https://www.npmjs.com/package/vso-node-api

Comment: it is TFS 2015
i would make this connection without vso if possible

Comment: Possible duplicate with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072327/tfs-2015-rest-api-authentication

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this via a javascript client, you could use the  invoke as follows:

```
var self = this;
        self.tasksURI = 'https://<SERVER>/tfs/<COLLECTION>/<PROJECT>/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0';
        self.username = "<USERNAME>"; //basic username so no domain here.
        self.password = "<PASSWORD>";

        self.ajax = function (uri, method, data) {
            var request = {
                url: uri,
                type: method,
                contentType: "application/json",
                accepts: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(self.username + ":" + self.password));
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {
                    console.log("ajax error " + jqXHR.status);
                }
            };
            return $.ajax(request);
        }

        self.ajax(self.tasksURI, 'GET').done(function (data) {

            alert(data);

        });
```

More details please refer this similar question in SO: [TFS 2015 REST API Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072327/tfs-2015-rest-api-authentication)

Comment: if they use Windows-Authentication
how can make the connection, i thought to use (PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN) but in TFS-2015 there is no (PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN).
what do u think ??
thank u anyway