# How to pass NTLM credentials using angular http post call?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-401, ntlm-authentication

I am working on localhost where angular and web api using 2 different ports that's causing issue now.

I am trying to call web api c# from angular like this

> ````
> this.http.post<AccessToken>(`${this.url}/api/Home/Eid/?code=12345sfffs`,{headers:this.httpHeaders})
>        .pipe(Response => {
>          console.log("hi");
>          console.log(Response);
>         return Response;
>         }); ```
> ````

But I am getting below error

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

When I tried in postman also I got same 401 error and later I fixed by adding NTLM credentials in postman to get 200 response.

But how to pass NTLM credentials from angular post call?
And why web api expecting for NTLM credentials?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: TL;DR: add `withCredentials: true` to your `options` object. Be aware that the user's browser needs an extant NTLM/Kerberos session with the remote host, and this won't work over the Internet.

Comment: Pass your token or values of authentication through Header.

Comment: @KiranJoshi [NTLM/Kerberos is managed by the browser _and_ client OS, and the browser does not expose that information to scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527749/javascript-ajax-ntlm-authentication). The token/headers are only accessible to the browser (like a `httponly` cookie).

Comment: @Dai Thank you so much, it's worked! Thanks for everyone for your responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified my angular post call to this

```
  return
 this.http.post<AccessToken>(`${this.url}/api/Home/Eid/?code=12345sfffs`,{headers:this.httpHeaders},{
withCredentials: true })
        .pipe(Response => {
         console.log("hi");
         console.log(Response);
         return Response;
         });
```

In Web API, I have modified web.config to this

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>       
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200"/>               
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />              
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```